# Off topic "other stack exchange network "-- limited options why?

Tags: feature-request

is there any merrit to having a new more options in that list, like :

- SuperUser.stackexchange
- Graphicdesign.stackexchange
- Photography.stackexchange
- stackoverflow

this is extra step seems so useless if there is only one option to pick.

[image]

Comment: This yet another thing which is addressed when we graduate.

Comment: cool. could I have read that anywhere?

Comment: How soon can we have the option to suggest that a question should be moved to a different stack exchange site than Blender meta? It seems to me that [question 46813](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46813/) belongs on Hardware Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have talked to two stack exchange employees and the short of it is we don't have enough questions needing to be migrated to warrant a custom list.

I know this comes as a bit of a disappointment, but I will share their reasoning for us not getting it.

First and foremost we have only migrated **33** ever, in the whole history of our site. That means we migrate about 1% of our questions away. The stats for this year are January: 3, February: 2, March: 0, Apil: 0 (so far). We just dont need to migrate questions that often.

Sometimes questions migrated to other sites can cause problems and tension.

With that few question needing to be migrated, and the problems it can cause they feel that BSE does not need the migration targets list.

---

So what are we supposed to do now?

Just flag any post you think should be on a different site. Use the "in need of moderator intervention" flag type, and use a message such as:

> This question belongs on < site name >

(Your flagging screen may look a little different, but the custom flag reason will always be at the bottom.)

[image: flagging dialog]

Comment: It would seem reasonable and proper to have at least one option besides the meta BSE option, namely a blank field in which we could nominate the SE to which we think the question would fit better.

Comment: @brasshat not really. First a "custom migration site" would not get the question moved there particularity fast. (that has to do with how the CV system works). Second simply flagging it with a custom message (the same amount of work) will guarantee a [mod](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) sees it and can move it. So I would ask why you want a field to nominate the the site, when you already have a field where you can nominate what site it should go to.

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from
**[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/278094)**

> If you **don't have 3,000 reputation**, the **site isn't in the list** of available migration targets, or the **question got closed without being migrated**, do not fret.

When we graduate we will get 5 sites to have on that list to migrate to (the devs set that up and it is all data driven). So in the not to distant future we **will** have other options (probably the sites you listed.)

For now just flag it with a custom message saying what site it should go to, and one of us mods will migrate it.

Comment: Well, we graduated a while ago, and as of the date of this comment, I **still** only see one site to nominate as a migration target: this one.

Comment: @brasshat after a (too long) delay I have the [answer](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/1063/2217) for you. Sorry for the delay.